# Should I go for ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

HI,

I want to create an application which requires SQL reports. By SQL Reports I mean using report viewer to show sql reports. I am new to MVC and my idea about MVC is that, dont use Server controls. Should I opt for ASP.Net MVC for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean report viewer, Crystal Reports or Reporting Services - you can use ASP.NET MVC and run reports on ASP.NET page. They can live side by side. In my current project I do just that - all of the application is MVC except for the reports viewer page. This is inside single IIS application - I use local web.config for few tweaks. But you can also dedicate a separate IIS app solely for ASP.NET reporting if you can't/don't want to run ASP.NET reports inside ASP.NET MVC applications.

I also found that sometimes generating reports in ASP.NET MVC as PDF documents and dynamically showing them inside iframe may be a better solution (cleaner and more printer-friendly for users).

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head. Yes ;)

Although "requires SQL reports" is not a very detailed requirement to go on, can you elaborate what you wish to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by "requires SQL reports" you suggesting it is very data intensive and you are thinking ORM (e.g. EF) is out of the question.

Weel, you can still use MVC with standard ADO.NET with stored procedures for your data layer. You can even use entity framework with stored procedures if need be.